# Flutter - Access color from LinearGradient()

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

I have a [LinearGradient()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html) from which I'd like to extract a color :

```
final niceGradient = LinearGradient(
 begin: Alignment.topCenter,
 end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  colors: [
    Color(0xFFC70000),
    Color(0xFFBBF000),
  ],
),
```

in Order to use say one of its colors in a Text(....colors:   )) or :

```
Container(
    color: #firstcolorfrom_niceGradient#)
```

Like this - How do you do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a color from a [LinearGradient()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html) just use its .colors[index] property

for example here :

```
    LinearGradient(
  colors: [
    Color(0xFFAF0000),
    Color(0xFF12F000),
    Color(0xFFFFA000),
  ],
).colors[2],
```

.colors[2] will get you the 3rd Color from this random LinearGradient()

-

So in your case just write :

```
Container(
color: niceGradient.colors[0])
```

to get the 1st color from your custom niceGradient ! : )

*Hope it helps !  : )*